# How to write multiline errorformat string?

Tags: syntax-error, opencl, vim, errorformat

I want to write OpenCL syntax checker for [vim-opencl plugin](https://github.com/petRUShka/vim-opencl). OpenCL compiler do some strange formatting of output errors. There are two types of errors.

Normal (with small error explanation):

```
"/tmp/OCLUKvOsF.cl", line 143: error: expression must have integral type
        rec_table[PRIME_P - ri] = PRIME_P - i;
                  ^
```

And not-normal with line-break in error explanation:

```
"/tmp/OCLUKvOsF.cl", line 148: error: a value of type "uint16" cannot be used
          to initialize an entity of type "uint"
    uint a = value, b = PRIME_P, u = 0, v = 0;
             ^
```

So trouble is in concatenation of two parts of broken error explanation in second case and normal error handling in first case.

I'm using [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) as generel syntax checker. Now I have such code for it:

```
let errorformat = '%E"%f"\, line %l: error: %m,%+C%.%#,%-Z%p^,'.
                  \'%W"%f"\, line %l: warning: %m,%-C%.%#,'.
                  \'%-G%.%#'
```

So first and second errors look following:

```
program.cl|143 error| expression must have integral type rec_table[PRIME_P - ri] = PRIME_P - i; ^
program.cl|148 col 14 error| a value of type "uint16" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "uint" uint a = value, b = PRIME_P, u = 0, v = 0;
```

It almost ok (especially in second case), but I don't know how to make it like this:

```
program.cl|143 col 19 error| expression must have integral type
program.cl|148 col 14 error| a value of type "uint16" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "uint"
```

Or at least like this:

```
program.cl|143 col 19 error| expression must have integral type rec_table[PRIME_P - ri] = PRIME_P - i;
program.cl|148 col 14 error| a value of type "uint16" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "uint" uint a = value, b = PRIME_P, u = 0, v = 0;
```

Do you have some idea?

UPD. Updated errorformat and expectations

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a useful way to test this but you need to escape your spaces with a backslash too.

I might also put a -space after the `%C`s so that they only match lines starting with a space.

Finally for warnings you're ignoring some lines and never have a `%Z` anywhere.  (I don't think you need the minus in front of the Z but I'm not clear on that; I don't use the minus myself.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's no need to escape spaces according to syntastic help: https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/blob/master/doc/syntastic.txt#L341

Comment: I will make experiment with %Z and space before %C