# What's the meaning of some advanced patterns in vim errorformat? (%s, %+, %\\@=)

Tags: vim, errorformat

I tried reading `:help errorformat` and googling (mostly stackoverflow), but can't understand some of the patterns mentioned there:

- `%s` - *"specifies the text to search for to locate the error line. [...]"*

  - um, first of all, trying to understand the sentence at all, where do I put the "text to search", after the `%s`? before it? or, I don't know, does it maybe taint the whole pattern? WTF?
  - secondly, what does this pattern actually do, how does it differ from regular text in a pattern, like some kinda `set efm+=,foobar`? the "foobar" here is for me also "text to search for"... :/
- `%+` - e.g. I [I've seen something like that used in one question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13256135/98528): `%+C%.%#`

  - does it mean the whole line will be appended to a `%m` used in an earlier/later multiline pattern? if yes, then what if there was not `%.%#` (== regexp `.*`), but, let's say, `%+Ccont.: %.%#` - would something like that work to capture only stuff after a `cont.:` string into the `%m`?
  - also, what's the difference between `%C%.%#` and `%+C%.%#` and `%+G`?
  - also, what's the difference between `%A` and `%+A`, or `%E` vs. `%+E`?
- finally, an example for Python in `:help errorformat-multi-line` ends with the following characters: `%\\@=%m` -- WTF does the `%\\@=` mean?

I'd be very grateful for some help understanding this stuff.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ah, `errorformat`, the feature everybody loves to hate. :)

Some meta first.

- Some Vim commands (such as `:make` and `:cgetexpr`) take the output of a compiler and parse it into a `quickfix` list.  `errorformat` is a string that describes how this parsing is done.  It's a list of patterns, each pattern being a sort of hybrid between a regexp and a `scanf(3)` format.  Some of these patterns match single lines in the compiler's output, others try to match multiple lines (`%E`, `%A`, `%C` etc.), others keep various states (`%D`, `%X`), others change the way parsing proceeds (`%>`), while yet others simply produce messages in the `qflist` (`%G`), or ignore lines in the input (`%-G`).  Not all combinations make sense, and it's quite likely you won't figure out all details until you look at Vim' sources. *shrug*
- You probably want to write `errorformat`s using `let &erf='...'` rather than `set erf=...`.  The syntax is **much** more human-friendly.
- You can experiment with `errorformat` using `cgetexpr`.  `cgetexpr` expects a list, which it interprets as the lines in the compiler's output.  The result is a `qflist` (or a syntax error).
- `qflist`s are lists of errors, each error being a Vim "dictionary".  See `:help getqflist()` for the (simplified) format.
- Errors can identify a place in a file, they can be simple messages (if essential data that identifies a place is missing), and they can be valid or invalid (the invalid ones are essentially the leftovers from parsing).
- You can display the current `qflist` with something like `:echomsg string(getqflist())`, or you can see it in a nice window with `:copen` (some important details are not shown in the window though).  `:cc` will take you to the place of the first error (assuming the first error in `qflist` actually refers to an error in a file).

Now to answer your questions.

> um, first of all, trying to understand the sentence at all, where do I put the "text to search", after the `%s`? before it?

You don't.  `%s` reads a line from the compiler's output and translates it to `pattern` in the `qflist`.  That's all it does.  To see it at work, create a file `efm.vim` with this content:

```
let &errorformat ='%f:%s:%m'
cgetexpr ['efm.vim:" bar:baz']
echomsg string(getqflist())
copen
cc

" bar baz
" bar
" foo bar
```

Then run `:so%`, and try to understand what's going on.  `%f:%s:%m` looks for three fields: a filename, the `%s` thing, and the message.  The input line is `efm.vim:" bar:baz`, which is parsed into filename `efm.vim` (that is, current file), pattern `^\V" bar\$`, and message `baz`.  When you run `:cc` Vim tries to find a line matching `^\V" bar\$`, and sends you there.  That's the next-to-last line in the current file.

> secondly, what does this pattern actually do, how does it differ from regular text in a pattern, like some kinda `set efm+=,foobar`?

`set efm+=foobar %m` will look for a line in the compiler's output starting with `foobar`, then assign the rest of the line to the `message` field in the corresponding error.

`%s` reads a line from the compiler's output and translates it to a `pattern` field in the corresponding error.

> `%+` - e.g. I I've seen something like that used in one question: `%+C%.%#`
>   does it mean the whole line will be appended to a `%m` used in an earlier/later multiline pattern?

Yes, it appends the content of the line matched by `%+C` to the `message` produced by an earlier (not later) multiline pattern (`%A`, `%E`, `%W`, or `%I`).

> if yes, then what if there was not `%.%#` (== regexp `.*`), but, let's say, `%+Ccont.: %.%#` - would something like that work to capture only stuff after a `cont.:` string into the `%m`?

No.  With `%+Ccont.: %.%#` only the lines matching the regexp `^cont\.: .*$` are considered, the lines not matching it are ignored.  Then the entire line is appended to the previous `%m`, not just the part that follows `cont.:`.

> also, what's the difference between `%C%.%#` and `%+C%.%#` and `%+G`?

`%Chead %m trail` matches `^head .* trail$`, then appends only the middle part to the previous `%m` (it discards `head` and `trail`).

`%+Chead %m trail` matches `^head .* trail$`, then appends the entire line to the previous `%m` (including `head` and `trail`).

`%+Gfoo` matches a line starting with `foo` and simply adds the entire line as a message in the `qflist` (that is, an error that only has a `message` field).

> also, what's the difference between `%A` and `%+A`, or `%E` vs. `%+E`?

`%A` and `%E` start multiline patterns.  `%+` seems to mean "add the entire line being parsed to `message`, regardless of the position of `%m`".

> finally, an example for Python in `:help errorformat-multi-line` ends with the following characters: `%\\@=%m` -- WTF does the `%\\@=` mean?

`%\\@=` translates to the regexp qualifier `\@=`, "matches preceding atom with zero width".

Comment: Ahhh, awesome, now I get the `%s`! So it's like what's in tags files, nice! As to `%+G`, now I'm surprised, message-field-only in qflist? will have to test, interesting, thanks! As to `%+A`: `:help efm-ignore` explicitly lists this as a possibility: *"e.g. '%+A'"*; are you still sure that's a syntax error? Finally, w.r.t. `\@=`, ouch... arcane regexp, you say? thanks, I didn't expect that, will have to read more too. That said, could you possibly share a link here for completeness? All in all, ***huge thanks*** and totally accepting the response! You're awesome :)

Comment: Looking at the sources, you're right: `%+` is supported for all (prefixed) formats, and the meaning is simply "add the entire line to the `message`, regardless of `%m`".  I'd imagine this is not very useful for the likes of `%A` and `%E` though. :)  I'll edit my answer accordingly.